# Read in multiple data types to a list

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ini

The title may be updated once the question is posted, But I start with an .ini file I would like to save Integers , Strings , Bool To this .ini file. Which I can do with

```
WriteString
WriteInteger
WriteBool
```

Then I Would like to read it into a list, Where when i pulled the data from the list it would know its all ready a integer or string or bool?

Currently I have to write everything as a string and then i read into a stringlist.

Comment: Read all your settings as ReadString  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, you can read all data  as string. And you can use the following function to determine the datatype:

```
type
  TDataType = (dtString, dtBoolean, dtInteger);

function GetDatatype(const AValue: string): TDataType;
var
  temp : Integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(AValue, temp) then
    Result := dtInteger   
  else if (Uppercase(AValue) = 'TRUE') or (Uppercase(AValue) = 'FALSE') then
    Result := dtBoolean
  else
    Result := dtString;
end;


You can (ab)use the object property of the stringlist to store the datatype:


procedure TMyObject.AddInteger(const AValue: Integer);
begin
  List.AddObject(IntToStr(AValue), TObject(dtInteger));
end;

procedure TMyObject.AddBoolean(const AValue: Boolean);
begin
  List.AddObject(BoolToStr(AValue), TObject(dtBoolean));
end;

procedure TMyObject.AddString(const AValue: String);
begin
  List.AddObject(AValue, TObject(dtString));

end; 

function TMyObject.GetDataType(const AIndex: Integer): TDataType;
begin
  Result := TDataType(List.Objects[AIndex]);
end;
```

Comment: Well currently i all ready know if the data value i pull from the stringlist is a int, string, or bool.  I would just like to stop doing StrtoInt(value from stringlist) and StrToBool(value from stringlist)  So can i assien the data type in the stringlist? or any list type. Sorry if i did not explain correctly first time

Comment: Updated answer to include datatype.

Comment: Read about such types as Variant and TValue with implicit automatic conversion